# Эффект шума ( grain )

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть ли код или инструмент с помощью, которого можно реализовать **эффект шума** на заднем фоне сайта ? Я нашел идеальный вариант, но он на canvas и я не знаю, как его добавить на задний фон своего проект. 
Пример :
https://codepen.io/renarsvilnis/pen/YWKRvE

```
<canvas class="grain">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `canvas` правило `position: absolute;`, `top:0`, `left: 0;`. После чего можете располагать элементы на переднем плане, они будут в основном потоке, расположение `canvas` не будет влиять на них. Если `canvas` будет перекрывать элементы основного потока, то попробуйте уменьшать значение `z-index` для `canvas`.